# Two big columns that are centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

What’s the best way to create the layout below? (responsive)

I have tried to split everything up into parts and use the transform property, however, I have some problems applying it to the boxes on the left respective right side. I am not sure though if this layout is the best one and if it’s working on most phones, computers etc.

How would you guys solve this problem?

Layout (computer):

[image]

Responsive layout (phone):

[image]

This is how my script looks so far, not the best:

```css
.page-4 {
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: #ffd9d2;
 z-index:3;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.page-4 .box {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.page-4 .box .group {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.left {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
}
 
.right {
    float: right;
    max-width: 50%; 
}
    
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-4">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="group">
  
   <div class="left">
    <div class="page-4-heading">TEXT1</div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="right">
    <div class="page-4-text">TEXT2</div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem or do you need more help?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer, I got busy with something. It did kind of help, I did some minor changes to your script and now it works perfectly :) Thank you for your help, I'm upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `Flexbox`

[Here is fiddle where you can resize the visible area and see it change](https://jsfiddle.net/r0y9z496/1/)

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrap > .item {
   border:solid 3px black;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrap > .item {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <section class="item">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</section>
    <section class="item">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.page-4{
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.page-4 .box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-4 .box .group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.left, .right{
  width: 720px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-4">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="group">
  
   <div class="left">
    <div class="page-4-heading"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora hic voluptatum qui, consectetur harum exercitationem. Mollitia, at nesciunt cumque veritatis quia temporibus ex necessitatibus, voluptas suscipit explicabo ab, quos blanditiis.</div></div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="right">
    <div class="page-4-text"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quam, illum, dicta repudiandae ab quisquam dolore fuga nihil perferendis nesciunt vitae reprehenderit blanditiis porro esse? Vel rem eligendi numquam accusamus!</div></div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How about using `display: flex`?

And the 2nd suggestion is that

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  /* Mobile */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) {
 /* Desktop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.page1,.page2{
width:50%;
height:300px;
background:grey;
padding:10px;
border:3px solid black;
}
.content{
border:1px solid black;
background:grey;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
.page1,.page2{
width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class='page1'><div class="content"> some text</div> </div>
<div class='page2'><div class="content">another text </div></div>
```

**For any query please comment**